# passing a column as parameter in python function

Tags: python, string, list, function, parameter-passing

I have been trying to store unqiue values in a column from pandas data frame using the following code to further use in the function. Code snippet:

```
def mergeFields(data,field):

    oldlist = pd.unique(data[field])

data_rcvd_from_satish.tags = mergeFields("data_rcvd_from_satish","tags")

Error: 
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not list
```

I know the error which i have been getting is similar to many other question still I am not able to resolve the error. I would request not to consider this duplicate and please answer.

Comment: What type should `data` be? Some kind of pandas thing? Because right now, you're passing in a string.

Comment: yes data is a pandas data frame.

Comment: If you do `print type(data)` inside your function, I believe you'll find that it is _not_ a pandas data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is a string. Please review the arguments passed to `mergeFields`. you basically wrote:

`"data_rcvd_from_satish"["tags"]`

which is invalid.